# Incorrect error C3489 in msvc 2017?

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2017

Should this code compile?

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    [=, b]{ return a; };

    return 0;
}
```

msvc 2017 version 15.6.1 gives me an error:

```
error C3489: '&b' is required when the default capture mode is by copy (=)
```

Same code compiles fine on gcc 6.3: https://ideone.com/HzdiJw

---

Workaround from [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)'s comment: `[=, b_=b]{ return a; };`.

Comment: ideone doesn't do well with warning/error reporting: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee41bb7f29c7491

Comment: Suggest using gcc.godbolt.org instead of ideone.com, which suppresses diagnostics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was illegal in C++14:

> `[C++14: 5.1.2/8]:` *[..]* If a *lambda-capture* includes a *capture-default* that is `=`, each *simple-capture* of that *lambda-capture* shall be of the form “`& identifier`”. *[..]*

And still is in [the current working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4727.pdf):

> `[N4727: 8.4.5.2/2]:` *[..]* If a *lambda-capture* includes a *capture-default* that is =, each *simple-capture* of that *lambda-capture* shall be of the form “`& identifier`”, “`this`”, or “`* this`”. *[..]*

It's unlikely it became legal in C++17 then was made illegal again.

Furthermore, [GCC 6.3 *does* complain about this code](https://godbolt.org/g/Jjz3gZ), so the ideone.com environment is building without `-Werror`, then reporting a successful build without passing along warnings.

Comment: hm. But it has meaningful usage. Imagine, that b is a `shared_ptr` that keeps alive some indirectly used context for lambda… Anyway this is offtopic for this question. Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: I didn't look _very_ hard, but I can't see a matching bug on GCC's Bugzilla.

Comment: @magras: I think that's what stuff like `[=, _b=b]{ return a; }` is for

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not a bug.  [GCC does warn](https://godbolt.org/g/Jjz3gZ) and error's with `-Werror`.